# What is Visual Studio 2010 going to look like?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have heard several podcasters (most recently the guys on [DotNetRocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/)) say that the look and feel of Visual Studio 2010 has been completely redesigned and Visual Studio rewritten in WPF.

I have been watching some [demos on channel9 of the Visual Studio 2010 CTP](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Visual-Studio-2010-and-the-NET-Framework-40-Week/) and the only thing that looks different to me is the opening screen.

I read the [notice on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2008/sep08/09-29VS10PR.mspx), but it doesn't say anything about the look/design of Visual Studio.

Has Microsoft reversed direction on this or are there going to be major changes made to UI of the final product?

Comment: I think this question will be updated with more accurate answers next week. They're releasing the next VS10 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's way too soon to make guesses about what it will look like: I don't even think that they know what it will look like.

However, from what I've heard, they are in fact rewriting portions to be WPF/C#, but they are not throwing everything out and starting from scratch. Instead, they will be rewriting  portions as it makes sense. For example, I saw that they have some new UML tools that definitely look to be done in WPF.

Comment: No it isn't.  The beta is publicly available.  It is written in WPF (its obvious from some of the graphics).

Comment: If it too soon to make guesses about what it will look like, why are podcasters saying it is completely redesigned? Where is this info coming from? I can't find it on Microsoft/MSDN.

Comment: Well, they've said several times that 1) They're switching to WPF for the GUI and 2) that there have been no big visual changes to VS since VC6 (implying that now it's high time they make some changes), but they haven't said much specifically about what it will look like.

Comment: I don't think you guys are getting the part where the Visual Studio 2010 CTP, obviously built with WPF, and loaded with new features, is available for download.

Comment: @Jason. Have you downloaded it? Have you seen the size of it?

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing 3D with a space theme. You'll be able to "fly through" your code, "orbiting" classes, "shooting down" bugs and "launching" your code.

Comment: What's the space metaphor for multithreading?  I'm excited about this!

Comment: only if i get to wear 3d glasses

Answer (score 2):

Uh, the beta has been available for over a month.  I have been playing with Visual Studio 2010 on and off.  It is very similar to 2008 in overall design.

You can download it here and see for yourself where they are taking the product:

**[Download Page at Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=922b4655-93d0-4476-bda4-94cf5f8d4814&displaylang=en)**

Comment: Historically, haven't they added the new UI goodness later in the game, though?  At least with the first VS.NET, it looked a lot like VS6 until the final beta, IIRC.

Comment: Really, you are referencing VS 6?  That was 10 years ago under a completely different software methodology at MS.  Today MS releases betas/CTPs early and often.  I have downloaded CTPs for the Orcas extensions, 2008 and other, recent tools.  They have been fairly accurate to the final result.

Comment: That's my point. The CTP looks very similar to 2008 but I keep hearing the UI is completely redesigned.

Comment: Well it similar, but there are obvious enhancements and anyone that has worked with WPF immediately recognizes the new visual stuff.

Comment: 2008 was *similar* to 2005, but the details are what make it so much nicer.  I see the same level of improvement in 2010.

Comment: @Jason. If that is the case, that is fine with me. I was just expecting a "revolutionary" new interface. I guess it's still a long way away.

Comment: The first beta for VS.NET was released in the summer of 2001, so it wasn't actually 10 years ago! :)  I didn't mean to say that was my only data point, but I think the magnitude of the UI diffs has been similar through all the VS releases since then, maybe VS.NET -> 2003 excepted.

Comment: @Chris, you said 6 not 7.  Visual Studio 6 was release in June of 1998 according to Wikipedia, which jives with my recollection of moving from VB 5 to VB 6.  Not trying to harp on the point :-)

Comment: Jason, I believe this early demo was done before any serious work had been done on the UI redesign.

Answer (score 2):

There are a metic ton of videos on Channel9 about [VS2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Visual+Studio+2010/), [TFS 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Visual+Studio+Team+System+2010/) and then the [PDC 2008 sessions](https://sessions.microsoftpdc.com/) online as well.  They are also starting a new series called [10-4](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/) dedicated just to VS2010 - a walk through of sorts.

Comment: Yes there are. I have been going through them and I don't see what changes are being referred to.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that its going to have a [historical debugger](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Historical-Debugger-and-Test-Impact-Analysis-in-Visual-Studio-Team-System-2010/).

Also- this should prob be a wiki

Answer (score 1):

Let's pray that they don't dink with anything, visually.  My #1 guess is that they'll try and wrap the new office ribbon bar around our necks. ;|

Comment: It's been a few years since VS .Net came out... Maybe they should remap all the key combinations again

Comment: No, they've said that the ribbon is completely wrong for VS, so I don't think you'll be seeing it.

Comment: As I said, "Let us pray."  They'll find some way to make it work, just for the sake of it.  Never say never.

Comment: They could introduce a new type of dock window where any accidental mouse movement re-aranges all your windows, I always enjoy those.

Answer (score 1):

From [WPF Wonderland](http://wpfwonderland.wordpress.com/):

[Visual Studio 2010 gets WPF facelift](http://wpfwonderland.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/visual-studio-2010-gets-wpf-facelift/)

WPF has been out for a couple years.  That’s long enough that new releases of Microsoft products are sprouting WPF interfaces.

Last year at PDC Microsoft announced that the code editor in Visual Studio would be re-written in WPF.   Microsoft didn’t stop at the code editor though.  Today Jason Zander, GM for Visual Studio, [revealed the new WPF based IDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2009/02/20/a-new-look-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Highlights from the PDC Keynote #1 on Day 2 (see: [PDC website](http://www.microsoftpdc.com))

- Multi-monitor support for the IDE via
  WPF.
- Building classes from test classes.
- Toggle TFS bugs over a code segment
  in Debug mode.
- Partial config files for debug,
  release.
- WYSIWYG Silverlight Designer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out (although I am having trouble finding where the keynotes are on the PDC site).

Comment: Ah. Couldn't find it on the PDC site, but see it now on channel9.